# Flutter - Sembast Database insert List of Objects

Tags: database, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm about to use the database "Sembast" in Flutter.
Simple objects with data types like string and int are working properly. However, it becomes problematic when using Lists.

I have created an example and oriented myself on the following tutorial: https://resocoder.com/2019/04/06/flutter-nosql-database-sembast-tutorial-w-bloc/
In my example, there are fruits and leaves as objects. A fruit contains a list of leaves.

```dart
class Fruit {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final bool isSweet;
  final List<Leaves> leaves;
...
}

class Leaves {
  final String id;
  final String name;
...
}

//Create a sample object
var leaveOne = Leaves(id: "1", name: "leaveOne");
var leaveTwo = Leaves(id: "2", name: "leaveTwo");
var leaveThree = Leaves(id: "3", name: "leaveThree");

var leavesList = List<Leaves>();
leavesList.add(leaveOne);
leavesList.add(leaveTwo);
leavesList.add(leaveThree);

var fruit = Fruit(id: "1", name: "Apple", isSweet: true, leaves: leavesList);
_fruitDao.insert(fruit);


// The fruitDao.insert makes following
Future insert(Fruit fruit) async {
  await _fruitStore.add(await _db, fruit.toJson());
}
```

The JSON looks like that: {id: 1, name: Apple, isSweet: true, leaves: [Instance of 'Leaves', Instance of 'Leaves', Instance of 'Leaves']}

The ERROR is following: 
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): value Instance of 'Leaves' unsupported type Leaves

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed at, `Instance of 'Leaves'` is not a valid type so each `Leave` must be converted as well. Hard to guess what you are doing without seeing your `toJson()` but something like this should work (could be largely optimized):

```dart
class Fruit {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final bool isSweet;
  final List<Leaves> leaves;

  Fruit({this.id, this.name, this.isSweet, this.leaves});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'isSweet': isSweet,
        'leaves': leaves?.map((leave) => leave.toJson())?.toList(growable: false)
      };
}

class Leaves {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Leaves({this.id, this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{'id': id, 'name': name};
}
```

and your json should look like something this this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Apple",
  "isSweet": true,
  "leaves": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "leaveOne"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "leaveTwo"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "leaveThree"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I'm using "json_serializable" - package. So this generates me the code for the function `toJson()` and `fromJson()`. 
If I edit this generated file (usually you should not do this), and paste your code to map the leaves (`'leaves': leaves?.map((leave) => leave.toJson())?.toList(growable: false)`) - it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example in addition to @alextk answer with converting to and from without any code generation or library's.

```
class Fruit {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final bool isSweet;
  final List<Leaves> leaves;

  Fruit({this.id, this.name, this.isSweet, this.leaves});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'isSweet': isSweet,
      'leaves': leaves.map((leave) => leave.toMap()).toList(growable: false)
    };
  }

  static Fruit fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Fruit(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
      isSweet: map['isSweet'],
      leaves: map['leaves'].map((mapping) => Leaves.fromMap(mapping)).toList().cast<Leaves>(),
    );
  }
}

class Leaves {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Leaves({this.id, this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }

  static Leaves fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Leaves(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a static fromMap method you can very well use a Factory method

Answer (score 2):

For cases when you use freezed, I found this solution:

```
...
...
@freezed
class Fruit with _$Fruit {
//add this line
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
const factory Fruit({...}) = _Fruit;

factory Fruit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FruitFromJson(json);
}
```